# What is an example of a stateful app in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, stateful, arr

I was reading about ARR affinity in Azure and saw that stateful apps should have ARR affinity enabled:

[image]

I assume this is so the same VM is used for future requests for that client.

But is it even possible to store state on VM?

I thought we don't have access to those low level details in our app service.

What would be an example of a stateful app in Azure where you'd be able to store state on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

A Stateful service when it make use of some existing data, it means service has a memory. Its output is not 100% the function of an input. In order to function, the service needs to retain and access some set of stored information over some period of time.

Azure App Service enables you to easily create enterprise-ready web and mobile apps for any platform or device and deploy them on a scalable cloud infrastructure.

Suggest you to refer below articles for detail understanding.

- [Common web application architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures)

  [Scalable web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/scalable-web-app)

What is ARR affinity:

ARR identifies the user by assigning them a special cookie (called as an affinity cookie), which allows the service to choose the right instance the user was using to serve subsequent requests made by that user. Which means if we have the ARR Affinity enabled, a client is tied to a specific web worker until the session finishes.

Azure WebApps by default have ARR Affinity cookie enabled, this cookie pairs a client request to a specific server. However, Azure Web Apps is a stateless platform and, in an environment, where we are scaling the Website across multiple instances, the ARR Affinity cookie will be bound to a specific server. It’s advisable to avoid the use ARR cookies in a scaled environment where we have multiple instances that serve our application requests.

Disabling ARR cookies is a sustainable resolution for issues related to ARR Affinity cookies in scaled environments, where these cookies rely on the relationship with the worker machine they are paired with.

Also, this is good for legacy application compatibility as they may not have been designed with load balancing in mind.

But if your app has been designed for load balancing (i.e. your app is stateless, session state stored elsewhere), you should disable this.

Comment: How do you know where your session state is stored? We're running an ASP.NET 4.8 SQL backend, AngularJS frontend app as an Azure app service, and we're using ASP.NET Membership.